# Phonegap, facebook login x-frame-options deny

Tags: cordova, facebook-graph-api, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

I'm trying to create mobile application with phonegap and framework7. Now I'm trying to login in facebook. I'm using phonegap-facebook-plugin which is under my control. I'm building it locally and I can change its code (although it's not desirable in the final version, I can experiment if it's needed.)

My code is as follows:

```
$$("#fb_login").on("click", function() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.login(["public_profile"],
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
    });
```

When I hit login for the first time , I'm receiving an error Refused to display , x-frame-options is set to DENY:

```
Refused to display 'https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=xxx&client_id=xxx&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&scope=public_profile&sdk=joey' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

In network on my chrome I verified that it's set so:

```
General
    Request URL:https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?app_id=.........
Response Headers
    x-frame-options:DENY
```

In my understanding this header is set by facebook and I can't change that fact (setting it on my server won't help at all). But I don't use iframes or at least I don't see any traces of them in the html. The only iframe I'm seeing in my html structure is the iframe that facebook creates under it's div

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
```

The things get even more complicated after I hit login for the second time. I successfully received the facebook access token.

*On the bright side, every click after first one logs me in :)*

Anyone with hints what I'm missing and how can I log when I click for the first time?